# oracle sql : how to rename 2 column in the same time

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT last_name,salary,department_id FROM HR.EMPLOYEES 
WHERE salary IN('17000','9000') AND DEPARTMENT_ID IN('60','90');
Alter table HR.EMPLOYEES rename column last_name to Employee AND
Alter table HR.EMPLOYEES rename column salary to "Monthly Salary";
```

> i need to rename "last_name" to "Employee "  And "salary " to "Monthly Salary"
>
> Message by oracle : SQL command not properly ended

Comment: According documentation this is not possible. Why do you like to rename column `SALARY` to `"Monthly Salary"`? In general it is possible to have mixed-case and space characters for column names, however this is very uncommon. Do you just like to beautify your output? Better do this in client application or by a view.

Comment: it's a question by our teacher , thank you so much for yours advices MR Wernfried Domscheit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just want to do it in the query using `AS` to specify an alias:

```
SELECT last_name AS Employee,
       salary    AS "Monthly Salary",
       department_id
FROM   HR.EMPLOYEES 
WHERE  salary IN('17000','9000')
AND    DEPARTMENT_ID IN('60','90');
```

However, you can [rename each column](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53457) individually:

```
Alter table HR.EMPLOYEES rename column last_name to Employee;
Alter table HR.EMPLOYEES rename column salary to "Monthly Salary";
```

*(But you should probably avoid using case-sensitive column names - otherwise you will have to use the double-quotes column name with the exact case in every statement.)*

Comment: Thank you so so much MTO

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do this

```
Alter table HR.EMPLOYEES rename column last_name to Employee ;
Alter table HR.EMPLOYEES rename column salary to "Monthly Salary";
```

I would just get rid of 'AND' and finish the command with ';'

Comment: Tahnk you so so much Jany86